# FastReport custom object as Datasource

Tags: c#, fastreport

I developed a simple print report in FastReport to print some details in table object.

Now I want to let my users to design and adjust their print report so I store report XML in database and load in FastReport Designer to user.
now to bind information in table.

We must add datasource in designer from database only and after that a connection is open and select all records to user and ...

My problem is that I want to use Custom Entity Object as Datasource for report not database table. How can I do that?

So if possible when the user opens report designer he can adjust column remove or add and drag new columns from datasource to report table and when save that report.

I run print by passing list to RegisterData function of report and it is ok.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass list of any objects to the RegisterData method, look at the DataFromBusinessObject example.